# Reference a typescript file as a library in script lab

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-addins, scriptlab

I have written a super small logger in a typescript class and placed it in a file call `Log.ts`. The file also contains a type definition. I would like to reference it as a library so that I can create an instance of that class in the script lab script. How do I do that?

I have placed the `Log.ts` file on a public website and referenced it in the Libraries tab in script lab but it is not getting picked up.

What do I need to do to be able to create a new logger as `const log = new Log()`?

### Update

I have tried to create a minimal example. This is now the `log.ts` file:

```
export type PongType = "pong";

export class Log {
  ping(): PongType {
    return "pong";
  }
}
```

I have compiled this to a `log.js` as:

```
var Log = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Log() {
    }
    Log.prototype.ping = function () {
        return "pong";
    };
    return Log;
}());
export { Log };
```

I have then placed `log.js` on a public server and then tried to import it in the HTML section in script lab as suggested in the comments. This is done as:

`<script src="https://somedomain.com/log.js"></script>`

But I still don't understand how I could create an instance of `Log()` in the Script lab script.

Comment: Did you try using the logger in your Office add-in project?

Comment: Yes. I have started on an add-in as well and in there all I do is `import { Log } from "./log";`and then I can create a new log instance.

Comment: You are referring to the local file in that case. Have you tried using the hosted file in your Office add-in project?

Comment: You are right. I used the local file in the add-in. I tried to use the hosted one but I can't figure it out. All the guides I have found online only reference `.js` files and then they have separate type definitions. I was hoping to just reference the `.ts` file and get both the implementation and the type definitions. But maybe that is not possible.

Comment: You can generate the .js file and upload it to any web server. Only then you will be able to call a function from that file (if it is referenced from the HTML page).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't a way to have Script Lab load TypeScript code directly from a .ts file using the Libraries tab. Script Lab can load public npm packages and JavaScript bundles. For example, the Office JS API is loaded as a JavaScript bundle from a .js file hosted on a CDN. I recommend you try compiling your logging code into a JavaScript bundle or publish a public npm package.

Answer (score 0):

The `ScriptLab` add-in allows running JS/TS code, but not loading external web pages with links to external scripts. If you need to run an external script from a file hosted anywhere on the web JS file you need to embed a reference to it to the HTML page to get it loaded. TS file must be processed before by the compiler to get JS. There is no way to run .ts files directly.

Due to the fact that `ScriptLab` is a Microsoft tool/add-in, I guess you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.